# The setText method replaces existing text, and the append one enters new text succeeding a new line; how do I just concatenate QStrings back to back?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qstring

All the Qt widgets have either a SetText that replaces existing text and an append that adds a new line before adding the QString, but is there any method to concatenate text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just do it manually using `setText()`:

```
widget->setText(widget->text() + "new text");
```

Comment: What if the widget is a textBrowser? (It will not have a text() method)